# Connecting to a Minecraft Server that is used for Hamachi networking but is local to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, minecraft-java-edition-server, hamachi

If I create and install the Minecraft Server Jar on an older desktop computer, that will act as a "dedicated" Server PC, and port the Server to be used by my friends via the Hamachi VPN, would I still be able to connect to said Server, that is located on my local network, even though the Hamachi VPN IP Address is being used in the Server Config File?

***Long Story Short***

What I want to know is, if I have a Server running on a seperate computer on my local network, but has been configured to be used on Hamachi networking, would I still be able to access the Server from another computer on the same local network, but not on the Hamachi VPN?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Fabian i have not, as I do not have a older desktop to try it on. This question is just something I thought about earlier in the day :D

Comment: @Malco What I want to know is, if I have a Server running on a seperate computer on my local network, but has been configured to be used on Hamachi networking, would I still be able to access the Server from another computer on the same local network, but not on the Hamachi VPN?

Comment: @GipsyD Great edit, much better now :)

Comment: How would you accept the correct answer then? Would you just believe any answer?

Comment: Of course not. I dont know how to do it or if it is even possible. My only option is to see what answers appears in the mean time as I try and find a PC from somewhere local

Comment: @GipsyD Do you have and Android phone? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.boardwalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This done assuming we are on Windows, yet configuration should be the same as other platforms*

So you want to connect to a server on your local network, but - understandably - you don't want to connect from your PC, through VPN encryption, to your modem, to Hamachi, back to your modem, again with encryption, to your PC/Server, back and forth.

As far as I know most guides advise you to type the IP address Hamachi gives you as the `server-ip=` parameter in the *server.properties* file which is located in your server folder. That IP Address should **not** be in the 192.168.1.x address range.
Now, what you need to do is **replace this IP with 0.0.0.0**

*Why this works*

Essentially what this does is tell the Minecraft server to run on all IP Addresses (ie. all networks and adapters) that are available to your PC, effectively extending your server availability beyond the mere VPN of Hamachi.

On the client PC (the one used to play) you will type in the IP Address of the server on the local network (you can find it with `ifconfig`) and on your friends' PCs as you already know you will use Hamachi and the IP it provides.

Also, port forwarding doesn't bite. It's a much more flexible, powerful, efficient and easy (from the client side) way to host a Minecraft Server. It also deals with the atrocious lag caused by Hamachi. Give it a try!

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer. Thank you for your submission. I will try this ASAP as soon I can find a PC that is in working order

Comment: This solution solved all my problems with my Minecraft Server! Thank you! I really do appreciate it!